# redirect from and to subdomain with htaccess base on browser language

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect my users in homepage base on their language.
I think I've to use 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language}`
but I can't figure out.
My last try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com [R,L]


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://en.mydomain.com [R,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://fr.mydomain.com [R,L]
```

But this generate an infinite loop.

Folder structure

- htdocs/index.php ->mydomain.com
- htdocs/en/index.php  ->en.mydomain.com
- htdocs/fr/index.php -> fr.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the HOST isn't already pointing to the correct place:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^en.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://en.mydomain.com [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^fr.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://fr.mydomain.com [R,L]
```

Comment: everything is fine with es language, but it goes on loop with english language...

Comment: The rules looks consistent, so they should all work the same. Try clearing your browser cache/history, or try a different browser to test it. When I use Chrome, I notice it will cache the original attempts, and not use the new redirect rules.