# mod_rewrite default redirection to missing segments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need some assistance of writing 2 proper mod_rewrite rules for a website.

Basically I have the following structure:

`http://www.website.com/subsite/lang` (e.g www.website.com/corporate/en) followed by other url segments. Everything works fine.

What I need to do, however, is to:

1. Force redirect to `http://www.website.com/default/` when visiting www.website.com and (if) first segment (sub-site) was omitted. This can be hard-coded value.
2. Detect broswer $lang with .htaccess and redirect to `http://www.website.com/subsite/$lang` if language was not specified in the URL.

What is the proper way to do these two rules with .htaccess?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511378/redirect-from-and-to-subdomain-with-htaccess-base-on-browser-language may help.

Answer (score 0):

1 is simple enough:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /default/ [L,R=301]
```

But 2 requires parsing of the accept language header, and that's not as simple as a regex and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if 1st segment is not there send to /default
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(default|corporate)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /default/ [L,R=301]

# if language was not specified in the URL then send to /corporate/$lang
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:default|corporate/[a-z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /corporate/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sweet! This almost works. However, I'm being redirected to something like ```http://www.website.com/corporate/en-US,en%3bq=0.8``` instead of simple 'en' at the end. Is there a way to fix this?

Also I only have 3 languages. 'fr', 'en' and 'de'. I'd like to be redirected to 'fr' if none of 3 langs are detected

Comment: Ok let me try to fix that

Comment: Thanks. It's much better. I'm actually being redirected to proper URL ```http://www.website.com/corporate/en``` but the page now returns:
```This webpage has a redirect loop```

Comment: Almost there! One last thing: The page now always redirects to 'corporate'. I needed it to redirect there be default is no segment was specified.. So I'm unable to change the URL to .. say.. ```http://www.website.com/contact/en```. it jumps back to 'corporate'